# How to convert a semicolon-separated string into spreadsheet rows in excel or MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel

I have a MySQL table for published books, with one row per book. The two columns relevant to this question are *itemnumber* and *contents*.

*Contents* is a semicolon-separated string containing all the chapter titles (no page numbers).

Example *itemnumber* = 'QW1234' *contents* = 'Alpha;Beta;Gamma;Delta;Blues;Funk;Ska'

I need to create a new table where each chapter *title* (e.g. 'Alpha,' 'Beta') gets its own row (with the *itemnumber* duplicated to another column in each row, in the format: | item number | title |
QW1234 | Alpha |
QW1234 | Beta | ...etc.

Is there a for each method for doing this in MySQL, looping through the semicolon-separated strings in a single cell?

If there's a way to accomplish this in Excel I can export the table. My suspicion is that SQL will be easier but I'm in the dark on this one.

Comment: Usually this sort of question is about splitting a comma-separated string into rows, but the same solutions can be used for semicolon-separated strings. No, it's not a task that is easy or recommended in SQL.